# LibGDX android translating spritebatch sometimes jumps 1-2 pixels forward (lag)?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am making my first game using LibGDX on android.

I have a background which is 288*511, Now in my game, I need to repeat that background and then translate over it. I have made that game for desktop using Slick2D, and had the same problem, just a bit lower than on my LG G2 phone (4.0.4), is there a way to fix this lag or I am doing something wrong?

The problem is that when it's translating, its moving fine and sometimes jumps 1-2 pixels forward or just stuck for 0.5 seconds or so.

This is my class:

```
public class Background {

    private class RepeatedBackground implements GameObject {

        private int x;
        private int y = 0;
        Sprite background;

        public RepeatedBackground(int x, Sprite s) {
            this.x = x;
            this.background = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void render() {

        }

        public float getPreferedWidth() {
            int w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            return (float) (w / 1.15);
        }

        public float getPreferedHeight() {
            int h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
            return (float) (h / 1.15);      
        }   

        @Override
        public int getX() {
            return this.x;
        }

        @Override
        public int getY() {
            return this.y;
        }

        public Sprite getSprite() {
            return this.background;
        }

    }

    private int tra = 0;
    private long traTime = 0;
    private List<RepeatedBackground> backgrounds = new ArrayList<RepeatedBackground>();
    private Level level;
    private SpriteBatch backgroundRenderer;

    public Background(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
        this.backgroundRenderer = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    public void generateBackgrounds() {
        int x = 0;
        Sprite background = this.level.getFactory().createBackgroundSprite();
        for (int i = 0; i < LevelConfig.MAX_BACKGROUND_REPEATS; i++) {
            this.backgrounds.add(new RepeatedBackground(x, background));
            x += background.getWidth();
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        this.backgroundRenderer.getTransformMatrix().translate(-6, 0, 0);
        this.backgroundRenderer.begin();
        this.backgroundRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(this.level.getInstance().getCamera().combined);
        Iterator<RepeatedBackground> itr = this.backgrounds.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            RepeatedBackground b = itr.next();
            Sprite s = b.getSprite();
            if (b.getX() - b.getPreferedHeight() < this.level.getInstance().getCamera().viewportWidth) { // this doesn't work properly, but it doesn't load all backgorunds at once but still lags..
                this.backgroundRenderer.draw(s, b.getX(), b.getY(), b.getPreferedWidth(), b.getPreferedHeight());
            }
        }
        this.backgroundRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

My create values for camera:

```
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(w,h);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ParallaxBackground class from here

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1795

It doesn't depends on the size of the image or camera. It just translates your background continuously

source: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ParallaxBackgound